# How to compute the ergodic mean of a series?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, macroeconomics, ergodic

In a paper, the authors say, "We can thus approximate welfare by computing the ergodic means of log consumption and log consumption growth from long simulations of the model.". They use the approximated welfare for other simulations in their paper, but they do not show how to compute the ergodic mean. How to compute it?

Comment: what is the model?

Comment: Ergodic mean is approximated by standard average for ergodic series. Check `ergodic theorem`.